# JSP данные после валидации с submit не уходят на сервлет

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, servlet, валидация

Проверяю на валидность страничку регистрации.
Вот JSP:

```
<form action="controller" name="reg" method="post">
        <div class="registration-block" id="firstnamee">
            <label for="firstname"><fmt:message key="firstname"/></label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
        </div>

        <div class="registration-block" id="emaill">
            <label for="email"><fmt:message key="email"/></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
        </div>

        <div class="registration-block" id="passwordd">
            <label for="password"><fmt:message key="password"/></label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"<br>
        </div>

    <div class="registration-button">
        <input class="registration-button" type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="to_register"/>"
        onclick="return validate(this.form);">
    </div>
</form>
```

Вот JS код:

```
function showError(container, errorMessage) {
    container.className = 'error';
    var msgElem = document.createElement('p');
    msgElem.className = "error-message";
    msgElem.innerHTML = errorMessage;
    container.appendChild(msgElem);
}

function resetError(container) {
    container.className = 'registration-block';
    if (container.lastChild.className == "error-message") {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
}

function validate(form) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var elems = form.elements;

    var res = true;
    resetError(elems.email.parentNode);
    if (!elems.email.value) {
        res = false;
        showError(elems.email.parentNode, ' Укажите пароль.');
    }

    resetError(elems.password.parentNode);
    if (!elems.password.value) {
        res = false;
        showError(elems.password.parentNode, ' Отсутствует текст.');
    }
    return res;
}
```

После submit данные должны уходить на сервлет. При некорректных полях функция отрабатывает и показывает неправильные input-ы (данные на сервлет не уходят). При корректных полях функция отрабатывает но данные на сервлет не уходят. Как сделать чтобы данные при корректных данных уходили на сервлет, а при некорректных - нет?

Comment: Вызввать preventDefault только при некоректных данных.

Comment: да. так и есть. уже разобрался. спасибо за ответ